# How to disable windows hotkey ALT+F4 in Kivy app?

Tags: python, windows, kivy, kivy-language

Does Kivy offer any of the functions for disabling windows hotkey (ALT+F4) to your app?
Or can I do this through python 3.5+ ?

Answer (score 0):

You can redefine stop in your app-class and you only call super(MyApp, self).stop() if you want to quit. However you need an overlayed widget wich overloads on_close, that you can quit with [escape] in which you write super(MyApp, app).stop().

Answer (score 0):

```
class MyApp(App):

def build(self):
    Window.bind(on_request_close=self.on_request_close)
    return My_Grid()

def on_request_close(self, *args):
    return True
```

I use this code to detect the "event : close",it did work.
But my gridlayout setting is not functioning now.

```
Config.set('graphics','fullscreen',0)
```

Comment: I just solved the (Config.set) issue,by moving my config to the top of my .py file before importing anything from Kivy.